# React Native - camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync() is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-camera

Writing a React Native app using the `expo-camera` library. I need to match a supported aspect ratio of the camera to the screen size but the `getSupportedRatiosAsync()` function from [the expo-camera documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#getsupportedratiosasync) is returning this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync is not a function. (In 'camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync()', 'camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync' is undefined)]

Stack trace:
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
  node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

Here's a minimal example of the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default class RecordingScreen extends React.Component {
    camera = null;

    state = {
        hasCameraPermission: null,
        camRatio: "16:9"
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const camera = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        const audio = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
        const hasCameraPermission = (camera.status === 'granted' && audio.status === 'granted');

        this.setState({ hasCameraPermission });

        const camRatios = await camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync();
    };

    render() {
        //Rendering code here
    };
};
```

Has this function been deprecated? Should I be importing it differently?

Comment: You're using the response from `Permissions.askAsync`, which isn't expo-camera. Try the uppercase variable you're importing (`Camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync();`).

Comment: I've tried this and throws a similar error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _expoCamera.Camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync is not a function. (In '_expoCamera.Camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync()', '_expoCamera.Camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync' is undefined)]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `expo-camera` creates a `this.camera` implicitly which can be used to call this function:
`const camRatios = await this.camera.getSupportedRatiosAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Create a useRef() hook.

```
let cameraRef = useRef();
```

Set it to 'ref' in 'Camera' component.

```
 <Camera ref={cameraRef}>
```

Now you can use it like this :

```
const camRatios = await cameraRef.current.getSupportedRatiosAsync();
```